# Zoom controls for MapBox Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to enable zoom controls for Mapbox Android but neither XML

```
mapbox:mapbox_uiZoomControls="true"
```

nor Kotlin/Java

```
mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
```

work for SDK 8.6.1 - both seems deprecated. Any ideas how to enable this control and if it's available at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, correct. There is not any way to set ZommControl in the latest version of Mapbox. [see](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/13198)

Answer (score 0):

done it by myself

1. Create a button.
2. Attach the button to the function.

private MapView mapView;

public void zoomIn(View v){
mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(new CameraOptions.Builder().center(mapView.getMapboxMap().getCameraState().getCenter()).bearing(mapView.getMapboxMap().getCameraState().getBearing()).zoom(mapView.getMapboxMap().getCameraState().getZoom() + 1.0).build());
};

Comment: Plz format your code as per community guidelines